# HP Envy 6430e doesn't scan area selected in preview window

Tags: drivers, hp, scanner, hplip, sane

I recently acquired a HP ENVY 6430e and set this up with HPLIP-3.21.4 on Xubuntu 16.04 and HPLIP-3.23.12 on Xubuntu 18.04. Printing/photocopying is OK. I then installed hplip-3.21.4-plugin and hplip-3.23.12-plugin to get scanner working. In both cases I'm using Xsane v0.999.
This is OK provided the scan area selected in the preview window starts at the top left corner. If the area selected is elsewhere on the platten, the scanner scans the selected size but always starts its scan at the top left hand corner.

After digging around a bit I noticed that the .drc (device settings) file contains the parameters for the scan area: tl-x tl-y and br-x br-y.
The values for full platten A4 scanning are:
tl-x = 0 tl-y = 0 br-x = 13744028 br-y = 19185826
[image: Full platten A4 scan]
The values for a scan of the centre area of the HPLIP test page x: 4cm -> 16cm y: 5cm -> 25cm are:
tl-x = 2627876 tl-y = 3744143 br-x = 10534763 br-y = 16232371
[image: Scan of centre area]
This suggests to me that Xsane/sane is receiving the correct scan area data from the preview window but the scanner is not receiving the instructions to act on it.

I have determined that this is not a hardware limitation or malfunction as the scanner works as expected from HP_Smart app on MacBook-Pro. So the issue lies with either HPLIP or Xsane.

[image: Scan of centre area of platten using MacBook-Pro and HP_Smart]

I should add that I have an old OfficeJet 6950 and a Canon LiDE 400 both of which work fine on the same set-up, straight "out-of-the-box".

Any guidance you can offer on this problem would be much appreciated.
jg

Comment: You haven't mention any on-topic OS, both 16.04 & 18.04 reached EOSS/EOL (*depending on architecture*) long ago.

Comment: [Ubuntu 18.04 LTS reached *End of Standard Support* last year](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/06/17/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-18-04-lts-began-on-may-31-2023/), and is thus off-topic on this site.  You can use ESM/Pro support options (*cost maybe involved*) if you wish but community support (*such as this site*) no longer exists, though SE *Unix & Linux* allow all Ubuntu questions too.  Please see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic or Canonical who provide ESM/Pro services.